How do I connect CSS file to HTML file?
Image from vs code of how my files work

I need to connect styles.css from the main folder to entertainment/entertainment.html
how do I do it? The website keeps showing up without any images or styling on it and I am running out of ideas, couldn't find anywhere on internet because that solution I tried is the closest one from stack overflow I found.
I tried using ../../styles/styles.css but it did not work.

You only need to traverse one level up, ie href="../style.css". Your current directory is entertainment. One level up (..) is the main directory. From there you can reference the styles.css file (or styles directory, it's not clear from your question)
